# Can XPath 1.0 return XML Element names in manner similar to returning node attributes and text?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

The question(s):
        Can a XPath 1.0 expression return only the names of xml nodes (either qualified or not) and not the entire node? Is XPath 2.0 capable of same?

---

The detail:

I am profiling a series of well-formed xml documents for xml element node usage (ie. obtain aggregate counts of xml nodes across several xml documents). I have a perl script that retrieves a desired node-set of each document, then iterates over each node to obtain counts of the node names using the XML::XPath::Node::Element->getName. I have an alternate implementation that profiles xml node attributes and text values, but use an XPath statement to retrieve the "atomic values" (as opposed to using XML::XPath::Node::Element->getAttribute() or similar in perl).

[Note that I realize the "atomic values" are actually sets of attribute/ text nodes.]

I experience a 50-fold improvement in performance when allowing the XPath expression to return the desired "atomic values" as opposed to looping over results in perl, so I would like to retrieve xml node names in a manner similar to attribute (ie 'attribute::*' or '@*')and text (ie 'text()') nodes. I've looked over the XPath and XML specs, but have not been able to identify a solution.

edit: To be more specific, I'm looking for something like `'local-name(//*)'`, but something that returns a set of names for all matching nodes (as opposed to only the first node found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 is a filter; it can't generate content. If it's not a node in the DOM (element node, attribute node, text node, etc), it can't be returned. That means that strings can't be returned by an XPath query.

That's why `//*/local-name()` can't possibly work.

Comment: Agreed - I am dubious as to whether a solution exists, given the specification. However, I was hoping that there was an implementation not specified in the XPATH/ XML specs, such as an implied attribute node for a XML element -- something akin to `'//@name'`, where "name" is the implied attribute. To my knowledge, such an implied attribute does not exist (but thought someone else may have a workaround).

Comment: @WMX, I'm sure I would have heard of it if XML::LibXML generated attribute nodes on the fly for any reason. I wouldn't know if other XPath libraries actually implemented something other than XPaths.

Comment: Right - I was actually hoping for something that I had missed in the XPath spec, though it is looking increasingly unlikely. I similarly doubt that implementations would generate node independent of the spec (nor should they, I would think). Perhaps I'll make a suggestion for XPath 3.0 (though I haven't fully read the XPath 2.0 spec yet) :-)

Comment: Re "I was actually hoping for something that I had missed in the XPath spec", which is why my Answer says why that isn't possible.

Comment: Actually - went back to the spec, and XPath does provide for the return of other basic types (quote from spec): The primary syntactic construct in XPath is the expression. An expression matches the production Expr. An expression is evaluated to yield an object, which has one of the following four basic types:
*node-set (an unordered collection of nodes without duplicates)
*boolean (true or false)
*number (a floating-point number)
*string (a sequence of UCS characters) -- Though I agree that it does not appear that the functions that return string types will return a set of strings.

Comment: Marking this discussion as answer since it contains the most verbose dialog on the question. However - many thanks to the answer provided by @daxim, which included the first reference to an alternative to XML::XPath for XML processing (ie. XML::LibXML). Thanks to all who answered!

Comment: The statement that //*/local-name() can't possibly work is wrong. It doesn't work in XPath 1.0 but it does in XPath 2.0. Therefore downvoting the answer, even though it has been accepted.

Comment: @Michael Kay, Updated to restricted my answer to XPath 1.0. I don't know anything about XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

In the XPath 1.0 data model there is no such thing as a set of strings, therefore no way of returning the set of names of a set of nodes as a result.

In XPath 2.0 it's straightforward:

```
//*/local-name()
```

Comment: My apologies - I obfuscated the discussion by essentially asking two questions in the same thread. Thank you for providing an XPath 2.0 solution. I look forward to trying the solution once I can implement support for XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `local-name` function:

```
//*[local-name()='nodename']
```

Comment: Thanks, but use of the function in the predicate selects the entire xml node. I'm trying to extract only the xml node name -- something like this (though this is not a valid XPath expression) : local-name(//*)

Comment: Oops - local-name(//*) is valid, but only returns the first node found. I'd need a set of names.